# Python. Кодирование ip и порта в hex массив

Tags: python, list, ip

Смысл получить на входе строку '10.10.10.10:5000', а на выходе массив

```py
buf_list1 = '10.10.10.10:5000'.split('.')
buf_list2 = buf_list1[3].split(':')
ip_list.append(hex(int(buf_list1[0:2])))
ip_list.append(hex(int(buf_iist2[0])))
#И вот тут проблема задачи с портом  
>>['0xa','0xa','0xa','0xa','0x13','0x88']
```

Понятия не имею как разложить 2-х байтовое значение без проблем на 2 отдельных байта и как обратно собрать

Comment: Если есть переменная `port` в которой число, то `(port >> 8) % 256` это старший байт, а `port % 256` это младший байт

Comment: @entithat, ['0xa','0xa','0xa','0xa','0x13','0x88']

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, засунул в hex((port >> 8) % 256) и
hex(port % 256), сошлось, не подскажешь как объединить?

Comment: `(5000).to_bytes(2, "big")`.

Comment: А есть еще модуль ipaddress